# How to set existing artifact properties using the Artifactory plugin in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

Goal:
Use a declarative Jenkins pipeline to download an artifact from Artifactory, run a test, and set a property value of the artifact in Artifactory based on the test result.

Trouble area:
How to set artifact properties of existing artifacts using the Artifactory plugin in a Jenkins pipeline?

Some of the code:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage("Load") {
            steps {
                // Get the firmware from Artifactory
                script {
                    def artServer = Artifactory.newServer url: '~~~'
                    def downloadSpecInline = """{
                        "files": [
                            {
                                "pattern": "${artRepo}/*thing-*${artBuildNo}*-class.zip",
                                "recursive": "true",
                                "flat": "true"
                            }
                        ]
                    }"""
                    def artifactBuildInfo = artServer.download(downloadSpecInline)

                    // Unknown part
                    doSomeTest()
                    artifactBuildInfo.setProperty qa.level, awesome
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the plugin.

> ```
> def server = Artifactory.server "${_artifactoryServer}"
> def propsSpec = """{
>     "files": [
>         {
>             "pattern": "${my_repo}/*/*/${_filename}"
>         }
>     ]
> }"""
> server.setProps spec: propsSpec, props: "${_property}=${_value}", failNoOp: true
> ```

One thing to be careful of:  If you don't specify a filename, ie. it is zero length, the API will write the property to every artifact in the repo.